# Problems displaying two fields in same line in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am having this weird problem of displaying two fields in the same line. According to django docs, for that I just need to wrap the two fields in a tuple. For eg, lets say I have two fields A and B, so what I can do is

```
fields= (('A','B'),'C'.....)
```

However it is showing the following error,

`MyModel.fields` refers to field `'('A', 'B')'` that is missing from the form. Is it because of the version of django? This is really weird

Comment: Where did you read that exactly? As far as I know `fields` is used in [`ModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields) not model forms. Also you did not specify version of Django used.

Comment: I have definitely placed the fields=() information in the ModelAdmin

Comment: And on your models admin page it does not show fields in the same line?

Comment: It shows the error which I have mentioned above

Comment: My django version is 1.2.5. I think it is due to the version of django. It is supported from 1.3 onwards I guess

Comment: My bad, try using [ModelAdmin.fieldsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets) as it should be supported in older versions and has more or less same result. Also please use code format when posting tracebacks in question.